# Single Select SQL Statement for 2 different Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with a column called `Category`. In my user interface, I have a dropdown list of the category. User can select a category and click on a `Search` button to filter the results by the category. In the dropdown, the first option is blank. Means if the user wants to see all records from all categories, he can select blank.

In my SQL Select I have 2 statements for this

```
IF @Catg IS NULL
Begin
    Select * 
    From Table
End
Else
Begin
    Select * 
    From Table 
    Where Catg = @Catg
End
```

The `Catg` column in the table will have either a NULL or a category. Is this possible to do in a single SQL statement?

Comment: in addition to answers below, read this in your spare time: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: i posted one answer might be this is helpful for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `OR` statement to join the clauses together:

```
Select * 
From Table
Where Catg = @Catg OR @Catg IS NULL
```

Comment: This i cannot use, as if there is a proper Category, then i cannot show the NULL Values.

Comment: I was looking for something like a case statement which i can use in the where clause.

Comment: @user2561997 Have you tried using this? It will not show null values.

Comment: Lets say I have 4 Records in my Table and values in the Catg attribute are: A,B,C and NULL.
So when User select A on the UI, I will show just 1 Record, and when he choses Blank, I will show 4 Records

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE (Catg = @Catg) OR (Catg IS NULL)
```

Comment: This i cannot use, if there is a proper Category, then i cannot show the NULL Values.

Comment: I think you're missing an `@`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

might be `ISNULL` solve your problem this will check if values is `NULL` then `''` else your `VALUE`

```
select * from tblName
where ISNULL(Catg , '')= ISNULL(@Catg, ISNULL(Catg , ''))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.